# How to check if all of my elements have been hidden?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building this Notification tray:
[image: Notification tray]

and I'm trying to check and see if all the notifications are removed, and if so, hide the tray as well. It stays on the screen right now:
[image: It stays on the screen right now].

Here's a simple enough function to remove the individual notifications:

```
function removeNoti(btn) {

btn.style.display = "none";

}
```

and here's my HTML:

```
<div id="noti-tray-wrapper">
                <div class="notification" onclick="removeNoti(this)">
                    <div class="noti-tray">You have unread messages </div>
                    <div class="noti-tray-btn" id="n1">x</div>
                </div>
                <div class="notification" onclick="removeNoti(this)">
                    <div class="noti-tray">You have unread messages </div>
                    <div class="noti-tray-btn" id="n2">x</div>
                </div>
                <div class="notification" onclick="removeNoti(this)">
                    <div class="noti-tray">You have unread messages </div>
                    <div class="noti-tray-btn" id="n3">x</div>
                </div>
                <div class="notification" onclick="removeNoti(this)">
                    <div class="noti-tray">You have unread messages </div>
                    <div class="noti-tray-btn" id="n4">x</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

So how can I tell that all of the "btn" has been removed? So that way I can do some conditions to basically set the noti-tray-wrapper to display = "none" as well?

Comment: You would have to loop through each notification and check if it is hidden. If all are hidden, then hide the tray. Do this everytime you call `removeNoti`. And sidenote: inline event handlers (`onclick`) are outdated. They force you to write JS in HTML. Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of hiding your elements with `display: none`, actually remove the elements from the HTML (with the [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) method). If the tray is doesn't have any notifications (children) anymore, then you could hide it with the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `remove` then check for `children.length` and when it equal to zero you hide it.

Also avoid the inline event handlers `onclick` as they are outdated

```js
const notifications = document.querySelectorAll('.notification')
const tray = document.querySelector('.notification-tray')

notifications.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.currentTarget.remove()
  if (tray.children.length === 0) console.log('zero')
}))
```

```css
.notification-tray {
  background: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<div class="notification-tray">
  <div class="notification">
    <div class="noti-tray">You have unread messages </div>
    <div class="noti-tray-btn" id="n1">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="notification">
    <div class="noti-tray">You have unread messages </div>
    <div class="noti-tray-btn" id="n2">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="notification">
    <div class="noti-tray">You have unread messages </div>
    <div class="noti-tray-btn" id="n3">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="notification">
    <div class="noti-tray">You have unread messages </div>
    <div class="noti-tray-btn" id="n4">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
function removeNoti(btn) {
  btn.classList.add('hidden');
  
  const visibleCount = document.querySelectorAll(".notification:not(.hidden)").length;

  if(!visibleCount){
    document.getElementById('wrapper').classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper{
  background-color: #ff8888;
  border: 5px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.notification * {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="notification" onclick="removeNoti(this)">
        <div class="noti-tray">You have unread messages </div>
        <div class="noti-tray-btn" id="n1">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="notification" onclick="removeNoti(this)">
        <div class="noti-tray">You have unread messages </div>
        <div class="noti-tray-btn" id="n2">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="notification" onclick="removeNoti(this)">
        <div class="noti-tray">You have unread messages </div>
        <div class="noti-tray-btn" id="n3">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="notification" onclick="removeNoti(this)">
        <div class="noti-tray">You have unread messages </div>
        <div class="noti-tray-btn" id="n4">x</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
   

 function removeNoti(btn) {

btn.style.display = "none";

}
const n1 = document.getElementById("n1");
const n2 = document.getElementById("n2");
const n3 = document.getElementById("n3");
const n4 = document.getElementById("n4");
let remove =()=>{
  n1.style.display = "none"
  n2.style.display = "none"
  n3.style.display = "none"
  n4.style.display = "none"
  const container = document.getElementById("container")
if(n1.style.display == "none"){
 container.innerHTML = "<p>Notification  list is empty!</p>"
}
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
       <div class="notification" onclick="removeNoti(this)"  id="n1">
                    <div class="noti-tray">You have unread messages </div>
                    <div class="noti-tray-btn">x</div>
                </div>
                <div class="notification" onclick="removeNoti(this)" id="n2">
                    <div class="noti-tray" >You have unread messages </div>
                    <div class="noti-tray-btn">x</div>
                </div>
                <div class="notification" onclick="removeNoti(this)"  id="n3">
                    <div class="noti-tray">You have unread messages </div>
                    <div class="noti-tray-btn">x</div>
                </div>
                <div class="notification" onclick="removeNoti(this)"  id="n4">
                    <div class="noti-tray" >You have unread messages </div>
                  <div class="noti-tray-btn">x</div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="remove()">Remove all</button>
</body>
</html>
```